# Is there a way to set the page title by data-binding using Knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a viewModel with a `Title` property. I'd like to set the page title using that property. Here's what I tried already, which didn't work:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title data-bind="text: Title"></title>
</head>
<body>
   <span data-bind="text: Title"/> <!-- this displays the title properly -->
</body>
```

The browser title is blank/default instead of the value of my `Title` property.

Comment: I don't want to keep editing my answer - any chance putting this on your html tag works?  `<html data-bind="attr: { title: Title }">`

Comment: Also, can you bind the Title property on your ViewModel to something more mundane, like a span, and have it show up ok?

Comment: I updated my code a little. Yes, I can data-bind the `Title` in other places with success. It's only the page title that doesn't work.

Comment: @Adam, I tried the data-bind on the html element but that didn't work either.

Comment: I updated my answer - what I wrote should work - I just tested it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try giving your html element an id

```
<html id="htmlTop" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

and applying your viewModel to it

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("htmlTop"));
```

**EDIT**

This works for me; I just ran this page and the title said "Hello".  Double check your code for typos.

```
<html id="htmlTop">

    <head>
      <title data-bind="text: title"></title>

      <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-1.2.1.js'></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

          $(function () {
              var viewModel = { title: "Hello" };
              ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("htmlTop"));
          });

      </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @Byron - sorry - I have one last idea, then I think the reservoir will be dry :)  --- see edit

Comment: @ByronSommardahl How about passing the HTML-element, instead of just document? Something like `document.getElementsByTagName("html")`.

Comment: Nope.. that doesn't work either. I have a feeling 1) I'm using the wrong data-bind keyword, or 2) I can't data-bind to a title element.

Comment: Perfect. I think there was another problem getting in the way. This definitely works! Thanks.

Comment: I got this to work without adding the id to the <html> element by using:
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0])

Hope that works to streamline your answer.

Comment: I used the more generic solution `document.documentElement`

Answer (score 6):

In my eyes, this situations begs for an observable subscription.

```
...
<title>{FALL BACK TEXT}</title>
...
```

View Model

```
ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.PageTitle = ko.observable(null);
    self.PageTitle.subscribe(function(newValue){ document.title = self.PageTitle() });

    //change PageTitle to see your handy work in action
    self.PageTitle("Hello World!");

};
```

> **EDIT:** As an amendment to my previous answer, I'd like to put forth the following. Will my previous suggestion work? Yes, it works very nicely. However, DOM manipulation within the view model itself does not "exactly" follow the MVVM paradigm. The actual "best" approach would be to create a custom binding, which sets the document title on update of a particular observable.

```
...
<title data-bind="htmlDocumentTitle: PageTitle()">{FALLBACK TEXT}</title>
...
```

View Model

```
ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.PageTitle = ko.observable(null);

    self.init = function(){
        self.PageTitle("My page title from an obersvable");
    };

    //init the viewmodel
    self.init();
};
```

And finally our shiny custom binding to "listen" for changes to the observable (note the use of ONLY the update action)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.htmlDocumentTitle = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var fallbackTitle = "My document title";
        var title = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        if(!title || title == null && title == "")
            title = fallbackTitle;

        document.title = title;
    }
};
```

At first glance this solution may appear less scalable, but do keep in mind that we can create "pseudo-inheritance" with Knockout View Models using "call()".

Comment: Worked for me! This is a particularly handy way of going about it when you don't want to pollute your page header with KO markup that's only going to be used dynamically in a few specific cases.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) which sets `document.title` on update, then add the binding to the `body` element.

Comment: Have a look at the last example on the page I linked to above, the hasFocus one. It would be very much like that, except you wouldn't need the `init`, and the `update` would set `document.title` to `ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)` instead of using it in the `if` block.

Answer (score 3):

You can use knockout subscribe:

```
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.title = ko.observable(null);
  self.title.subscribe(function(newTitle) {
      document.title = newTitle;
  })  
}

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.title('Hello page');
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @Douglas's suggestion, my solution was to add a hidden `div` somewhere in the body bound to a computed value:

```
<div data-bind="text: currentPageTitle()"></div>
```

Then, in the value computation, I set the `document.title`:

```
self.currentPageTitle = ko.computed(function() {
    document.title = self.Title();
    return self.Title();
}, this);
```

This works perfectly for me