# Can I use knockout to bind the HTML document title?

Tags: knockout.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to set the page title by data-binding using Knockout.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649690/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-page-title-by-data-binding-using-knockout-js)

So the title tag in my HTML document looks like this:

```
<title data-bind="text:Title"></title>
```

But it doesn't work, maybe because the  tag is inside the html header?

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: yes thanks - I didn't find that question. This should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a custom binding, its super easy

http://jsfiddle.net/L3nPG/

To see the title in fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/L3nPG/show/light/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.pageTitle = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var title = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        document.title = title;
    }
};

ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.pageTitle = true;
```