# How can I use data-bind for meta content in the header?

Tags: knockout.js, meta-tags

I have a list of items on a page, that when selected will take the user to that specific item page.  Each page needs a meta tag with the item name and number. The page that is generated for each item is dynamic. I have been trying to use the Knockout bindings with no luck.

```
<meta name="DocumentType" content="ITEM">
<meta name="Number" data-bind="text: itemNumber">
<meta name="Name" data-bind="text: itemName">
```

In the rest of the page, I have been using data binding successfully using a view model and applyBindings.  I have included the itemName and itemNumber to the view model, so they will return results.  At this point, how can I data-bind the data to my meta tags?

I have tried to follow the documentation for Knockout using the attr tag: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html

I have also tried to do what was done for binding to the html title here:
[Is there a way to set the page title by data-binding using Knockout.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649690/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-page-title-by-data-binding-using-knockout-js)

I haven't had any luck with those.  I could be doing them wrong, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by applying the data bindings on the head element or you could also apply it on the html element as Chris Knoll mentioned in a previous answer.

Then proceeded to add the "text" binding to the title element:

```
<title data-bind="text: title"></title>
```

To bind a value to the content attribute of a meta tag a I created a custom binding:

```
// extra custom binding to bind content attribute of meta element
ko.bindingHandlers.metaContent = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
        let contentAttribute = 'content';
        if (contentAttribute in element) {
            let value = valueAccessor();
            let valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);

            if (valueUnwrapped)
                element.content = valueUnwrapped;
        }
    }
};
```

The meta element with data binding for the content attribute using the custom binding:

```
<meta name="description" data-bind="metaContent: description" />
```

For completeness my viewmodel:

```
export class Head {
    public title: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable("My title");        
    public description: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable("My description");

    constructor() {            
        ko.applyBindings(this, $("head")[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply data bindings to any DOM element.  You didn't provide how you called ko.applyBindings, but what I am using in my own project is like this:

`ko.applyBindings(pageModel, document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);`

By passing it the top level HTML element, any dom elements found under should be bound to the data-bind elements.